# Do all browsers handle searching multi-line with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Will all browsers (IE6+, FF3+, Safari 3+, Chrome) execute a javascript regex search across line boundaries in the searched string?  Example:

```
var sourceStr = "This is some text \nOn multiple lines\nAnd the 2nd line.";
sourceStr = sourceStr.replace(/line/g, "xxx");
```

Also, are there any good references of what regex features are or aren't supported in various browsers.

Comment: Some problems with IE, at least: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1917-Javascript-Multiline-Regular-Expressions-Don-t-Include-Carriage-Returns-In-IE.htm

Comment: have you tried on those browsers?

Comment: I don't have easy access to all those browsers right now (particularly  the older ones), so I'm asking for the experiences of others.  The reason I ask is that I have a faint memory that there was some sort of multi-line regex issue with IE, but I don't recall if it was this issue or something else.

Comment: Here is a very good tool to test your code on all IE versions: [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but if you use any char syntax - dot "." in regex patterns, you may need to change it to `[\s\S]` to match any chars across lines.

Answer (score 1):

The ECMA specification ([ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) dictates acceptable regular expression grammar and multiline support is explicitly mentioned. Section 15.10.2.6 in particular demonstrates the effect of multiline support on Assertions.

So, if the browser supports the ECMA-262 specification, then yes, it supports multiline.

Of course, you should endeavor to test your code before you can be confident it works. It wouldn't be the first time a browser has failed to implement a specification correctly.

EDIT:
To clarify, JavaScript 1.5 is fully compatible with ECMA-262, Edition 3. I understand the following browsers support JavaScript version 1.5 or higher:

- Safari 2.0 or newer (Mac)
- Camino 0.8 or newer (Mac)
- Firefox 0.9 or newer (Windows, Mac, Linux)
- Internet Explorer 6.0 or newer (Windows)
- Mozilla 1.2 or newer (Linux)
- Netscape 7.1 or newer (Windows, Mac)
- Opera 8.0 or newer (Windows, Mac, Linux)

Can't actually find a decent source for Chrome although I'd be shocked if it didn't support JavaScript >= 1.5.

Comment: I won't downvote this, but the OP was asking about specific browsers, and you're answering about a spec. Unless you mention which browsers are compliant with the spec, it's not really an answer, IMO.